# CMake + UWP resources and source_group

Tags: c++, cmake, uwp

I have successfully setup my project to build a UWP application using CMake. However, when dealing with resources, it appears that they need to be added as sources to the `add_executable` command, as well as set as `RESOURCE` in the target properties.

All the resource files have been copied to their desired locations on disk. However, when I generate the projects, all the resource files end up in the root folder of the project structure. I've tried adding the `source_group` command, similar to what I do for the .cpp/.h sources (which go under a "Source Files" folder), but this seems to have no effect. Here's the relevant portion from my CMake (using CMake 3.6.1):

```
    set(ResourceFiles "Package.appxmanifest" "Logo.png" ... etc)
    source_group("Resource Files" FILES "${ResourceFiles}")
    add_executable(MyExe ${projectSources} ${ResourceFiles})
    set_target_properties(MyExe PROPERTIES RESOURCE "${ResourceFiles}")
```

Is this possible, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Is your intention is to add the resource files in a resource folder? Try using this: file(COPY "[your source file/folder]" DESTINATION "[your destination folder]")

Comment: no, I think you've misunderstood the question. I've updated it to be very clear that it is the structure of the project, not the location on disk that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution for this? I am facing the same problem... Thanks.

Comment: It works for me now, although I didn't track what fixed it. I upgraded my version of CMake from 3.6 to 3.8, which may have been it. I also added VS_DEPLOYMENT_CONTENT=1 for all these items, but removing that now doesn't reproduce the original bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing everything right.

However, there's one little problem in your code, instead of

```
source_group("Resource Files" FILES "${RESOURCE_FILES}")
```

It should be

```
source_group("Resource Files" FILES ${RESOURCE_FILES})
```

Notice the **""** you have around RESOURCE_FILES that makes it fail to work.

If your intention is to put the resource files into some resource folder?

You can try using the following commands,

```
file(COPY "[your source file/folder]" DESTINATION "[your destination folder]"
file(GLOB asset_files "[your destination folder]")
source_group("assets" FILES ${asset_files})
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Your proposed change won't fix the issue. CMake interprets strings as lists, as long as they are semicolon delimited, so passing it as a list or string makes no difference.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito, I was referring to this file https://github.com/wpbest/cmake-win-store-app/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt, line 99, and I see using semicolon or not does make a difference.

Comment: To give you the benefit of the doubt, I tried it, and as predicted it makes no difference.